# How to close electron app via javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, electron

I am running an express app via electron.

Below is the main.js

```
   const electron = require("electron"),
          app = electron.app,
          BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

    let mainWindow;

    function createWindow () {
      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
          width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        frame: false,
        kiosk: true
      });
      mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
     mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

      mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
        mainWindow = null;
      })
    }

    app.on("ready", createWindow);
    app.on("browser-window-created",function(e,window) {
      window.setMenu(null);
    });

    app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
      if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
      }
    });



    app.on("activate", function () {
      if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
      }
    });
```

and below is a button in the view that upon click i would like it to close the app

```
<button id="close-btn"><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Close application</button>
```

Essentially I want to activate this part of the code once the button has been clicked

```
  app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
          if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
            app.quit();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 43):

you can use

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
let w = remote.getCurrentWindow()
w.close()
```

to close your app.

if you are using jQuery

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
$('#close-btn').on('click', e => {
    remote.getCurrentWindow().close()
})
```

if you are using Vue.js

```
<template>
    <button @click="close"><i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Close application</button>
</template>

<script>
    const remote = require('electron').remote

    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                w: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
            }
        },
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.w.close()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am using handle bars but will try using jquery

Comment: This is wrong. This just closes the browser window. On a Mac, the app will continue to run. On Windows it closes but only if all windows have been closed. You need to use app.close()

Comment: @AndroidDev Your answer is also wrong: it does not work if there is no app yet. I use process.exit() when my Electron app is both a GUI and CLI, and it doesn't create an app unless the GUI is indicated. You still need to kill the Electron process itself.

Comment: This requires the option enableRemoteModule: true in the BrowserWindow(): 
new BrowserWindow({
 webPreferences: {
            enableRemoteModule: true,
}
}

Answer (score 31):

I use the line below to close the app.

`window.close()`

Answer (score 29):

You can also use [app.exit](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appexitexitcode):

```
app.exit(0)
```

This seems to bypass any event listeners and force the whole app to exit immediately. (Be sure that is what you want though!)

Comment: const electron = require("electron");
app = electron.app;
app.exit();

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong way, If you run window.close(), it just close window that app still run background.

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote
let w = remote.getCurrentWindow()
w.close()
```

You should close app like this:

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote
let app = remote.app
app.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

in main.js

```
function createWindow(){
win =new BrowserWindow({
    icon:'./img/code_file.ico',
    frame:false
});
win.maximize();

win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname:path.join(__dirname,'./login.html'),
    protocol:'file:',
    slashes:true
}));
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  });
}
app.on('ready',createWindow);
app.on('Window-all-closed', () => {
  if(process.platfrom !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

when all window is closed app.quit() function closed the application;

Comment: Read full question then give suggestion. You may suggest `app.exit(0)` use in exist click event.

Comment: `drawin`? Did you mean [`darwin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform)?