# What do I need to do in order to automatically close an electron app, via an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, electron, desktop-application

In my app, I have put in **index.html** a full width & height `iframe` with its `src` attribute set to my website. What I am trying to achieve is close the electron app when a function on the website in the `iframe` is called.

Basically, I have an "*off.html*" file, which displays some stuff and when it's ready, it runs the function `loadDone()`. What do I need to type in that function to force the app to close?

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314039/how-to-close-electron-app-via-javascript

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?