# How to close Electron app via TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, electron, tslint

I am trying to find the correct way to close an Electron app. I make use of React and TypeScript within the app. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314039/how-to-close-electron-app-via-javascript) and found a way that works:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
let w = remote.getCurrentWindow();
w.close();
```

But, TSLint tells me now that the `require()` style import is forbidden. Is there a cleaner way to close the Electron app?

Comment: Older post on doing similar (though has typos) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314039/how-to-close-electron-app-via-javascript

Comment: tslint can be reconfigured... and tslint != typescript

Comment: @trebleCode The link you posted is the same as the link in my post.

Comment: @smnbbrv In other words the code example I posted is the right way to close an Electron app? What would I have to reconfigure within TSLint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to this in TypeScript is to avoid `require()`. So, instead of requiring Electron the way you do, better importing `remote` within the import section and then accessing the remote variable. Now TSLint should be happy again.

```
import { remote } from 'electron';

...

private closeWindow() {
    remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
}
```