# Unable to import electron related files into Vue 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

env:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Node: v14.15.0
Npm: v7.0.3
Vue: ^3.0.0
```

I'm using Vue with Electron, and trying to access the `app.quit()` method in a Vue component. However, anything Electron related seems to give me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at eval (index.js?bdb9:4)
    at Object../node_modules/electron/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:2062)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Module.eval (background.ts?43bc:1)
    at eval (background.ts:73)
    at Module../src/background.ts (app.js:1239)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (Draggable.vue?2c68:3)
```

I've tried using `import { app } from 'electron'`, `const { app } = require('electron')` and `import { app } from '../background.ts'`

Here is the full component (@/components/Draggable.vue):

```
<template>
    <div class="draggable">
        <p @click="close">close</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
const { app } = require('../background.ts')

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Draggable',
    methods: {
        close() {
            console.log('close')
            app.quit()
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

I'm really confused because posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314039/how-to-close-electron-app-via-javascript) seem to link them up just fine... (see answers)

I will link the repo [here](https://github.com/Highlands-College/tournament-app/tree/main/src).

Thanks

Comment: If you are accessing the app object from a browser window , then i think you have to use const app = require('electron').remote.app, also make sure the enableremotemodule in the browserwindow options.

Comment: Still the same error... It happened literally every time I import Electron and use it somehow.

Comment: Same issue. I created a bug report here https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/1135

Comment: I dont recommend adding the nodeIntegration to true, but instead of that, you can try window.__dirname = __dirname;// inside the preload script               please let me know if it works

Comment: is this the web window or the electron window?